# How to pass state values via the axios get url in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm now to react I want to pass a value via Axios URL which has been saved as a state. How can I pass this value? I retrieve empno via the get method by passing the id from a previous link;

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.retrievePosts();
  }

  retrievePosts() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/employees/${id}`).then(res => {
      if (res.data.success) {
        this.setState({
          empno: res.data.employee.empno,
          
        });
      }
    });
```

Im trying to pass empno in the same retrievePosts() method to get another value. I have currently implemented like this:

```
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/employees/alocation/${this.state.empno}`).then(res => {
        if (res.data.success) {
          this.setState({
              totalallocation: res.data.allocationcount,
            });

            console.log(this.state.totalallocation);
          }
        });

  }
```

The value seem to never pass as its output goes as "undefined". how can pass the empno state value which has been received via the URL?

Comment: What does `console.log(res.data)` give you?

Comment: GET http://localhost:5000/employees/alocation/ 400 (Bad Request) this is what I get when  I try to pass the value. The 1st GET method actually gets the value for empno, Ive checked with console log.

Comment: im trying to pass an int value, I checked the backend via postman and it successfully works, its only when I try to pass the int value via the frontend the issue occurs

Comment: Hi, could it be something as simple as a typo in the second URL, you have 'alocation', should this be allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make your code asynchornous to make it work. add `async` like this

```
async   retrievePosts() {...}
```

and then `await` after each case of `axios`

Answer (score 1):

in order to get the corect value, the second "get" call must happen after the first one, but it isn't (necessarily) the case here - so you have to options:

- don't use state, but instead, make the second axios call from inside the "then" block of the first. this way, you can make sure it happens in a sequential matter.
- instead of using promises, use axios in an asynchronious matter:
  https://www.better.dev/asynchronous-javascript-using-async-await

Comment: thank you very much I will try that toooo